# C# Entity framework, how to get the primary key from an object created from a Junction table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Create new APN Object and add IPSec object via the IPSecs Junction table. I then need to add the new IPSecID (primary Key) to the BuildType table.

```
APN newApn = new APN()

 newApn.IPSecs.Add(new IPSec
    {
                    EndPoint = vtcPriEndPoint.Text,
    }


newApn.BuildTypes.Add(new BuildType
                    {
                    TypeOfBuild = "IPsec",
                    TransportID = newApn.IPSecID   <---no option for this syntax
                     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined a many to many relation between `APN` and `IPSec` you will have to `for each` through the newApn's IPSecs and create `BuildTypes`for each of them.

That said, the `Id`of the new `IPSecs` will not be known until after you have called `SaveChanges` on the context. Alternatively you can assign each `IPSec`of the newAPN to the `BuildType`'s supposed `Transport` Navigation property.